# Serilog Map sink log text

Tags: .net, logging, serilog

I've been trying to get Serilog's Map sink to use, using sample from [Github: serilog-sinks-map](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-sinks-map). I can get it to write to log using this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .WriteTo.Map("Name", "Other", (name, wt) => wt.File($"./logs/log-{name}.txt"))
  .CreateLogger();
Log.Information("Hello, {Name}!", "Alice");
```

But the result is that "Hello, Alice!" Gets written into log-Alice.txt file. How can I write just that message without "Alice" to log-Alice.txt?

And if I log with

```
Log.Information("Hello", "Alice");
```

"Hello" gets written into log-Other.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property "Name" is only set when used in the message template. Otherwise Serilog does not know how to map the value "Alice" to a property.

So if you want to set this property you have to create a context, like this:

```cs
var logger = Log.ForContext("Name", "Alice");
logger.Information("Helping user {User} with question {QuestionId}.", "Janne Rantala", "59190740");
```

This wil log `Helping user Janne Rantala with question 59190740.` in the file log-Alice.txt.

So if you want to log everything in class `Foo` in the file `Bar`. You create your class like this:

```cs
public class Foo
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger = Log.ForContext("Name", "Bar");

    public void DoThings()
    {
       this._logger.Information("Hello");
       this._logger.Warning("world");
    }
}
```